# overflow error in Python using dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I get the below  error while trying to fetch rows from Excel using as a data frame. Some of the columns have very big values like `1405668170987000000`, while others are time stamp columns having values like `11:46:00.180630`.

I did convert the format of the above columns to text. However, I'm still getting the below error for a simple select statement (`select * from df limit 5`):

> Overflow Error: Python int too large to convert to SQLite INTEGER

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You describe the use-case as reading Excel using pandas. Where does SQLite enter the picture here?

Comment: Here is my sample code 

import pandas as pd
from pandasql import sqldf 
pysqldf = lambda q: sqldf(q, globals())

df = pd.read_excel(r'C:....\File.xlsx')
pdf=pysqldf(""" select * from df limit 1 """)

Answer (score 0):

SQLite INTEGERS are 64-bit, meaning the maximum value is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

It looks like some of your values are larger than that so they will not fit into the SQLite INTEGER type. You could try converting them to text in order to extract them.

Comment: tried converting the columns like this df1[["A","B","C"]]=df1[["A","B","C"]].astype(str) . but still no luck

Answer (score 0):

SQL integer values have a **upper bound** of `2**63 - 1`. And the value provided in your case `1405668170987000000` is simply **too large** for SQL.

> Try converting them into string and then perform the required operation

Comment: tried converting the columns to string  like this df1[["A","B","C"]]=df1[["A","B","C"]].astype(str) .Still not working